# How do you display custom Contact fields in Membership reports?

Tags: civireport

I have created some custom fields for Contacts and want to display these fields in a membership report that we call member mailing list.  However I am unable to see the custom fields for Contacts as display columns in the report even though they are marked as searchable

[image]

Comment: Do you see any core contact field in the columns? `first_name`, `last_name`, etc?

Comment: Yes I can see the core contact fields.  Just not the custom ones

Comment: can you share the screenshot of the report criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can open the report file from your codebase, you can add the entity name to the `_customGroupExtends` variable array initialized at the top of the file of almost every report in CiviCRM.

```
protected $_customGroupExtends = array('Contact');
```

The above line will include all contact custom set in your report. You can add `Individual`, `Membership` to display custom group extending these entities too.

To see which file is used for the report, you can refresh the result to get a `Developer` tab which contains the class name used to display the result.

[image]

So the file which is used in above report is -

`/path_to_civicrm/CRM/Report/Form/Member/Detail.php`

Comment: ok great I will try this and let u know if it works. Thank you

Comment: Hi Jitendra.how do I locate the file for this report to update the code?  Sorry Im having trouble finding it

Comment: updated the answer to locate the file for the report

Comment: Great - you can accept this answer with a green tick to complete this question on SE.

Answer (score 2):

Look for custom fields in a fieldset below the ‘standard’ report fields - here’s an example for another type of report - but clearly shows the custom data sets (if they have been marked searchable in the custom data set configuration) as fieldsets in the report - click them open and you’ll see the custom fileds

[image]
Second thought: Extended Report extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports - you can download/install it from your Manage Extensions screen. It introduces a number of report templates - some of which will have many customfields extended (in fieldsets) so no core code edit required.

Comment: Thanks KarinG  we already have extended reports but couldnt find one that meets our criteria.   The current report is showing me custom fields for memberships but I need to access the custom fields for Contacts

Comment: In that case you’lll have to either make the edit Jitendra mentions above directly in core or add a custom_php override and just override that report