# Custom data sets, search and display in CiviCampaign

Tags: custom-fields, search, reports, civicampaign

I am currently setting up CiviCRM for the small NGO I currently work for, and I am having a lot of trouble with CiviCampaign.

We use CiviCampaign to record every fundraising campaign the organization is running and to relate contributions, events and activities to it. As the organization is active in different countries, we have one coordinator in charge of each geographical sector we work in. Therefore, he is responsible for the fundraising campaigns of the projects located in the countries he's in charge of. Those projects can also include a local partner and one or several volunteers working locally.

I created a campaign for every project we have in the organisation, as donators can specify they want their money to be used for a specific project. I also added custom data sets to record the person in charge of the project, the volunteer affected, and the local partner that benefits from the projet.

However, it seems there is no way to see the details of a campaign (when I go to the dashboard, I only see the ID, the title, the description, start and end dates, campaign type, status, and if it is active or not). I cannot click the campaign to see all the information I have recorded, and I must click edit to see the custom data sets. I cannot find a way to use those custom data fields as criterias for the search engine either.

Basically, those issues make my custom data useless, as I cannot use it as search criterias and I can't even consult it.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Thank you in advance for your help.

wedYa

Comment: My quick looks suggests that Custom Fields for Cases are not then available either in Campaign Search nor in Campaign Reports. I haven't checked yet but these might be available via Drupal Views +/- Civi Entity. but not much help if you are not using Drupal

Comment: Also  check Extended Report extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports - you can download/install it from your Manage Extensions screen. It introduces a number of report templates - some of which will have many customfields extended (in fieldsets) so no core code edit required.

Comment: Also see this Q+A which is trying to resolve similar issue but not in the context of civicase: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24456/how-do-you-display-custom-contact-fields-in-membership-reports

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Just to be clear, my issue is with custom data in CiviCampaign, not CiviCase. I will have a look at the links you posted and will report back.

Comment: My bad. I was looking at CiviCampaign when I wrote my first comment - just a typo / brainfart

Comment: No problem. I tried ExtendedReport. This was almost what I needed. I will have to create a custom report to get exactly what I want though (which I was not able to set up correctly so far), but this should work. Thank you again