# How to add Contact and Case custom fields to an Activity report?

Tags: custom-fields, civireport, custom-reports

Awhile back, I have made a copy of the the CRM/Report/Form/Activity.php, placed it under custom_php and added additional custom Contact and Case fields to the report by updating

```
protected $_customGroupExtends = [    'Activity' ];
```

to

```
  protected $_customGroupExtends = [
    'Activity',
    'Contact',
    'Case',
  ];
```

I know this [question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24456/how-do-you-display-custom-contact-fields-in-membership-reports) indicates this was the proper way 4 years ago. I am wondering whether this is still the proper way to show Contact and Case custom fields on Activity report with the current version of CiviCRM 5.57.2?

Answer (score 0):

Yes `_customGroupExtends` will still work. You probably want to sync any changes in CRM/Report/Form/Activity.php from the last 4 years into your custom file. But there's an argument that the time would be better spent making a new searchkit search that replaces what the custom report does, but it's true not all civireport features are available yet in searchkit.

Answer (score 0):

I avoid creating custom php over-rides as it will need checks/updates when Civi is upgraded. I added the same thing using the extension. Below is an example how I achieved

```
function extensionname_civicrm_alterReportVar($varType, &$var, &$object) {
  if ('columns' == $varType && get_class($object) == 'CRM_Report_Form_Activity') {
    $permCustomGroupIds = [];
    $_customGroupExtends = $object->getVar('_customGroupExtends');
    $_customGroupExtends = array_merge($_customGroupExtends, [
      'Contact',
      'Individual',
      'Household',
      'Organization',
      'Case',
    ]);

    if (!CRM_Core_Permission::check('access all custom data')) {
      $allGroups = CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::get('CRM_Core_DAO_CustomField', 'custom_group_id');
      $permCustomGroupIds = CRM_ACL_API::group(CRM_Core_Permission::VIEW, NULL, 'civicrm_custom_group', $allGroups, NULL);
      // do not allow custom data for reports if user doesn't have
      // permission to access custom data.
      if (!empty($this->_customGroupExtends) && empty($permCustomGroupIds)) {
        $_customGroupExtends = [];
      }
    }
    $object->setVar('_customGroupExtends', $_customGroupExtends);
    $object->addCustomDataToColumns(TRUE, $permCustomGroupIds);
  }
}
```